# Movie Review Website

Tags: mysql

I have tables for a movie rating website which look like the following:

- Movies (MovieID, Title, Year)
- Ratings (ReviewerID, MovieID, Rating)
- Reviewers(ReviewerID, Name)

And I would like to write a query giving the name(s) of the favourite movie(s) of the reviewer that is the most generous. At the moment I have decomposed the task into two parts:

-finding the name of a reviewer's favourite movie:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Title FROM Movies
NATURAL JOIN Ratings 
WHERE rating IN (SELECT MAX(rating) FROM Ratings)
```

-finding the maximum average rating:

```
SELECT reviewerID, AVG(rating) AS avg_rating
FROM Ratings
GROUP BY reviewerID
ORDER BY avg_rating DESC LIMIT 1
```

But I'm not sure how I can connect these two queries. Using subqueries, it doesn't work because I can't user LIMIT within a subquery.
Does anyone know how to connect these two queries?
Or maybe a method without using subqueries?

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: sounds suspiciously like homework. have you tested all your subqueries? i.e. do you get a list of each reviewers average? can you then get the reviewer with the highest average? etc etc

Comment: Sorry my tables and queries weren't consistent. I have fixed them and added more details. Average rating is the average of all ratings that a reviewer has provided, so a reviewer can post only one rating per movie, but can rate multiple movies.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question - could you post sample data, with expected results please?

Comment: I'm trying to find out the name of the movie(s), and these movies are the favourite movies of a reviewer (i.e. movies that received the highest rating by a particular reviewer). This reviewer is the one who is the most generous on ratings. For a given reviewer, generosity means the average of the ratings that reviewer has given to the movie(s) she has reviewed.

Comment: Did you find a answer to your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT m.title
  FROM movies m
  JOIN ratings r
    ON r.movieid = m.movieid
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT reviewerID
         FROM Ratings
        GROUP 
           BY reviewerID
        ORDER 
           BY AVG(rating) DESC 
        LIMIT 1
     ) x
    ON x.reviewerid = r.reviewerid
 ORDER 
    BY r.rating DESC
 LIMIT 5;
```

or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like that :

```
SELECT Title FROM Movies
WHERE movieID = (
    SELECT movieID FROM Ratings WHERE reviewerID=(
        SELECT reviewerID, AVG(rating) AS avg_rating
        FROM Ratings
        GROUP BY reviewerID
        ORDER BY avg_rating DESC LIMIT 1
    )
    ORDER BY rating DESC
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT 1`.

```
SELECT m.Title
FROM Movies as m INNER JOIN Ratings as r USING(movieID) 
GROUP BY m.movieID
ORDER BY AVG(r.rating) DESC
LIMIT 1
```